# How to underline (rather than highlight) the current line in vim?

Tags: vim

I believe it's possible to get an underline under the current line, rather than a highlight.

This adds the highlight in my .vimrc:

```
set cursorline
```

This is what I've tried adding to get an underline:

```
:highlight CursorLine gui=underline cterm=underline
```

But it appears to make no difference.

I'm using vim 7.4.629 on Centos 6.7 through putty, if that helps.

Comment: try `:hi clear CursorLine` then `:hi CursorLine gui=underline cterm=underline`

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I realise now it was clashing with directives in my molokai colorscheme.  Another question; is it possible to have a solid white underline?  At the moment the underline matches the color of whatever text is on it.  So the line matches the syntax highlighting on the line, and changes color along it's length.  Thanks!

Comment: @Codemonkey, no it's not possible.

Comment: You might have to :set cursorline after you setting highlight

Comment: Use guisp to set the underline color, eg: hi cursorline gui=underline guibg=none guisp=#00ff5f

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try `:hi clear CursorLine`  to clear the current cusorline hl, then `:hi CursorLine gui=underline cterm=underline`

The color of underline is same as your `ctermfg` or `guifg`. You can either live with your "colorful" underline, or add `cterm/guifg` to make the underlined text and the underline same color.

### Additional info

To only highlight the cursor line when in insert mode

```
au InsertEnter * set cul
au InsertLeave * set nocul
```

Copied from another anser by @meteowrite

Comment: How, can you be specific?

Comment: @Codemonkey e.g. `:hi CursorLine gui=underline cterm=underline ctermfg=None guifg=None`

Comment: Hi, what do I have to put into the vimrc to get this permanently?

Comment: @clog14 just put the command without the call for command `:`. So it would look like: `hi clear CursorLine` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

`:set cursorline`

was the best solution for me, you can combine it with removing the cursorLine as the answer above mentions

Comment: possibly also `set culopt=line`

Answer (score 2):

For me it works best to highlight the cursor line only in Insert mode. To do so, I use the action snippet to activate cursor underlining (full line) whenever Insert mode is activated and later deactivating it upon leaving the mode.

```
au InsertEnter * set cul
au InsertLeave * set nocul
```

Comment: This is a very useful suggestion. I will try to add it to the accepted answer. Thanks